# How to sort WordPress pages?

Tags: sorting, wordpress-theming

I have created 9 pages which I ordered from 1-9. What I want is to list or display the pages link from 1-6 and also pages from 7-9 separately in the header.

My question is, how can I apply this code to WordPress:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_db WHERE pages <=6
```

Can I apply with this code `wp_list_pages` or is there another way to code it in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by doing two different calls to wp_list_pages using exclude within your array of arguments to specify the set of pages you need

extract from this page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages

exclude 
(string) Define a comma-separated list of Page IDs to be excluded from the list (example: 'exclude=3,7,31'). There is no default value. See the Exclude Pages from List example below.